# Why are some non-constant expressions allowed as operands of a constexpr comma operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, comma-operator

Consider a simple example:

```
int foo() {
    return 3;
}

template <int>
struct Bar {};

int a;

int main() {
    int b;
    //Bar<((void)foo(), 1)> bar1;  //case 1. compilation error as expected
    Bar<((void)a, 2)> bar2;        //case 2. no error (long shot but `a' has a linkage so maybe expected)
    Bar<((void)b, 3)> bar3;        //case 3. no error ? (`b' does not have linkage) 
    (void)bar2;
    (void)bar3;
}
```

I would say it is a bug but both the latest [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M9SjKoL7XJZBBqoD) and [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KmooahJNAKDbsvY9) accept the code so maybe I'm missing some relevant standard rule that makes the code valid?

Comment: an even simpler MCVE would be https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1s3HFz

Comment: Not an answer, just a suspect: with `(void)a, 2`, the compiler can just discard `a`; with `(void)foo(), 1`, the compiler has (excluding the "as-if" rule) to execute a not-constexpr function and discard the returned value. Waiting for experts, I suppose the problem is the execution of `foo()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied to the first argument of the comma operator unless it is volatile. Therefore, `(void)a, 2` and `(void)b, 3` are constant expressions.

See [expr.comma]/1

> ... the left expression is a discarded-value expression ...

and [expr]/12

> ... The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied [to a discarded-value expression] if and only if the expression is a glvalue of volatile-qualified
>   type and it is one of the following: ...